# почему по нажатии кнопки Directory.Delete(directoryName, true); не удаляет директорию?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DelFolderWindowsFormsApplication3
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var directoryName = "$RECYCLE.BIN";
        //   dir.Delete(true); // true => recursive delete
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222718/c-sharp-delete-a-folder-and-all-files-and-folders-within-that-folder
        if (Directory.Exists(directoryName))
            Directory.Delete(directoryName, true);
    }
}}[![Delete Folder][1]][1]
```

Comment: Проверьте, вызывается ли по нажатию кнопки ваш обработчик. Если да, то нажатие кнопки не имеет к вопросу никакого отношения, и вам стоит выкинуть всё лишнее (форму, `button1_Click` и тому подобное) из вопроса. Если нет, то удаление тут не при чём, и вам нужно выкинуть удаление из вопроса.

Comment: У вас в папке с программой есть директория с именем "$RECYCLE.BIN"? Если нет, то понятно, почему ничего не происходит. Если речь идет о системной директории, то не думаю, что у вас получится её удалить.

Comment: спасибо программа с корневой директорией работает, а мне нужно удалять $RECYCLE.BIN с диска С:\ , вот написал теперь выкидывает ошибку доступа к директории 'отказано в доступе по пути' https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5jig5E9hRMwbDh3eE9DbGVleUU/view?usp=sharing